# Help creating a remoteapp installer(msi) in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, windows-installer, remoteapp

Hi guys I have coded an application that need to support remote install, can anyone guide me on how to create the msi? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's a really broad question and the answer is going to depend on your application and what it's deployment needs are.   Maybe this book will help get you started:

[WiX: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML](https://www.packtpub.com/wix-a-developers-guide-to-windows-installer-xml/book)

Comment: Ok my question is basically about how to create the installer that when installed can be remotely  accessed via terminal services.
What does TS RemoteApp do?

RemoteApp programs are programs that are accessed remotely through Terminal Services and appear as if they are running on the end user's local computer. Users can run RemoteApp programs side by side with their local programs. A user can minimize, maximize, and resize the program window, and can easily start multiple programs at the same time. If a user is running more than one RemoteApp program on the same terminal server

Answer (score 0):

Ok find out how to here using the terminal servcises to generate the msi, but i don't know if this is possible with vs2008, Thanks

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519250(WS.10).aspx